# Error with BouncyCastle library 1.59 (NoSuchAlgorithmException)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, keystore

I have updated BouncyCastle library 1.49 to version 1.59 and I am getting the following error:

```
exception unwrapping private key - java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42

java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key - java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42

        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.unwrapKey(Unknown Source)

        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)

        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1226)
```

The code implemented is as follows:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", new BouncyCastleProvider());
keystore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(hexStringToByteArray(privKey)), passphrase.toCharArray());

Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();

String keyAlias = "";

while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    keyAlias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
}

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(keyAlias, passphrase.toCharArray());
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] arr = hexStringToByteArray(encriptedPin);
byte[] decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(arr);
return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
```

I have updated JCE Policy and it still does not work, as well as the .pk8 certificate.

Has anyone had this problem? Any additional information tell me.

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: The missing algorithm is "AES_256/CBC/NoPadding"

Comment: I am not declaring that algorithm in the code, is it due to the library? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is with this line (2) of your code `new ByteArrayInputStream(hexStringToByteArray(privKey))`. You need to validate your keystore file. What exactly is the format of the file you are loading?

Comment: The problem has been solved by adding the following line of code: `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` But I don't understand why not from the java.security file  `security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why it does not work statically? With the file java.security